# Extract metadata from website ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, httpresponse, meta

I have been going round in circles trying to extract `meta tag` information from external websites. I started of with a `XML` approach but due to tags link `doctype` etc, my application kept throwing errors.

I am now taking a `HttpResponse` approach, I know how to get the website back and stored in a variable as a string but

> I can't figure out how to extract a substring from the content in the
>   meta tags?

I have been searching for a solution to this problem for days. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to download, parse and query the external HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried it with meta tags but for HTML documents is the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) a good solution. For some examples see this [blog post](http://olussier.net/2010/03/30/easily-parse-html-documents-in-csharp/).